# "Where did you find Sara"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, american-english, british-english

I am pretty clear with this sentence interpretation, where i have added "from" with the sentence as in "Where did you find Sara from" but if i do not use "from" and simply say "Where did you find Sara" could the "find/sentence" be interpreted as ( We did not actually find Sara and we are asking a question, where did you search for Sara,eg in a car, in a house, where/location)?

Comment: You seem to be asking whether "where did you find Sara" could mean the same as "where did you search for Sara". Is that right?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan yes indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  "Find" does not mean the same as search. It means "successfully locate".

Using "from" is incorrect.  This can be illustrated by considering the sentences:

> I found Sara in the kitchen  (good)

> I found Sara from the kitchen (wrong, not idiomatic)

> I found Sara from in the kitchen (grammatically incorrect)

The question form "Where..." expects a location (an "in ..."  or "at ..." etc. prepositional phrase) as the answer. So you should not include the prepostion in the question.

Then the question "Where did you find Sara?" asks about the "finding" not the "searching". It assumes that Sarah has been found.  If you want to ask about the locations that were searched say "Where did you search for Sara?"

Comment: thank you and how about present perfect tense? Could i or could i not using "from" as in "Where have you found Sara from"?

Comment: @BilalZafar maybe you're confusing your sentence with  the formulaic **Where are you *from*?** There is no preposition at the end of "**Where did you find [her]**? / *Where was she found?* (PASSIVE) / *Where have you found her?* (ACTIVE)

Comment: No.  You dont say "I've found her from the kitchen" You say "I've found her in the kitchen"